# Face recognition with face_recognition and cv2 : empty encoding error Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have a problem running a python face recognition script, it works all right for some images, but in some cases, it gives me the error:

`unface_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(faceimg)[0]IndexError: list index out of range`

It seems the `unface_encoding` variable is empty(?), but I don't know why this happens to some faces and not to others and how to solve it. I have read the face_recognition but it didnt really help me.

I am kind of a beginner in face recognition (and python) so any recommendation or improvement would help me.

Here is my code:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2

known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("known_faces/person.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown_faces/faces.jpg")

image = cv2.imread("unknown_faces/faces.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(unknown_image)

known_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]

for face in face_locations:
    print(face)
    (a, b, c, d) = face
    faceimg = unknown_image[a:c, d:b]
    faceimg = cv2.cvtColor(faceimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    unface_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(faceimg)[0]

    results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_encoding], unface_encoding,0.5)
    print(results)
    if results == [True]:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (b, c), (d, a), (0, 128, 0), 2)
    elif results == [False]:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (b, c), (d, a), (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow('base', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Excuse me for any English errors,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `face_recognition` that extensively, but I have used OpenCV and other facial recognition libraries. Usually the returned "face" is a bounding box of `x, y, w, h`. The rectangle is usually created following `x, y, x + w, y + h`. If the `face_recognition` is similar, you're making your box incorrectly. Try

```
faceimg = unknown_image[a:a+c, b:b+d]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/490), you need to specify the face location if you already have it to `face_encodings()`

```py
with = faceimg.shape[1]
height = faceimg.shape[0]
unface_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(faceimg, known_face_locations=[(0, width, height, 0)][0]
```